# Help with Kohana ORM?

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Using the ORM, I want to be able to load all articles that posted, in which a user has made a comment.

comments table

```
comment_id
user_id
article_id
etc....
```

Using ORM, I can access all articles posted by a user, but how would I be able to access all articles in which the user has commented on?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Another problem is, if a user comments on the same article twice, that article will show twice.. how do I change the group by clause of one object from within another?

Also, how do I change the order of one object from another?

Im using 2.3.4.

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM within kohana is mostly ment for simple tasks. While I'm sure it is possible to do this in ORM I rather use normal queries for a bit more complicated tasks:

```
$this->db = Database::instance();
$this->db->query("
    select
        user_id
        article_id
        id as comment_id
    from
        comments
    left join
        articles
    on
        articles.id = comments.article_id
    where
        user_id = $user_id
    group by
        comments.article_id
");
```

something like this should do the job if I didn't make any errors

Answer (score 5):

In pseudocode, try this...

- In Article Model, Have `$has_many = array('comments');`
- In Comment Model, Have `$belongs_to = array('article');`
- And in the code where you query:

.

```
$comments = ORM::factory('comment')
                ->where('user_id', $user_id);
                ->find_all();

foreach($comments as $comment)
{
    $article_id = $comment->article->id;
}
```

Sorry this won't solve duplicate article entry when `$user_id` comment more than once in an article... You may need to do bit more research on top of this.